# How to call function in other ajax of function

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a change_flat_rates_cost() function, but it works only when loading the page. but it is necessary for me that function worked at each change of the field "city", (in checkout fields).
I have tried to use ajax function and to call there add_filter() function, but it doesn't help.
I do it to change delivery cost without reset of the page depending on the chosen city

**change_flat_rates_cost function (changes the shipping price)**

```
function change_flat_rates_cost($rates, $package) { 

$userid = get_current_user_id();

$meta_city = get_user_meta( $userid, 'billing_city', true );

if ( isset( $rates['shipping_method_1'] ) ) {
    if ($meta_city == 'City1'){
        $rates['shipping_method_1']->cost = 100;
    }

    if ($meta_city == 'City2'){
        $rates['shipping_method_1']->cost = 200;
    }

}
return $rates;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'change_flat_rates_cost', 10, 2 );
```

**ajax function:**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_change_shipping', 'change_shipping' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_change_shipping', 'change_shipping' );

function change_shipping() { 
global $woocommerce;

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'change_flat_rates_cost', 10, 2 );

die();
}
```

Comment: How are you calling your ajax function in jquery?

Comment: function is calling correctly, with it there are no problems. with echo "test" inside function, I will receive response. but add_filter() doesn't work there

Comment: Ok, and are you sure that the filter itself is called on the reloaded page? Eg firing from add filter not within the ajax function? You can test it also with hookr plugin or something like that..

Answer (score 0):

You can add filter as normal "add_filter". No need to put it there in ajax, because anyways there are conditions mentioned in your function.

So, do add_filter normally and instead of using add_filter in ajax function, you should use "apply_filters". This will call your custom shipping function.

I hope I've made it clear.